# How to compare two rows from same table while sorting in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I want to sort all data in custom manner with conditional statement. Firstly, I will check if column1 & column1 are same. If they are same then I will compare based on column3.

**Example**

| id | total_score | mcq_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 30 |
| 2 | 50 | 40 |
| 3 | 50 | 20 |

Expected output

| id | total_score | mcq_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 50 | 40 |
| 1 | 50 | 30 |
| 3 | 50 | 20 |

Comment: `Firstly , I will check if collumn1 & collumn1 are same` did you mean column1 and column2 ?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for co operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify both columns in `ORDER BY`. If the values in first column have a tie, the second column is considered (and so on):

```
ORDER BY total_score DESC, mcq_score DESC
```